# React Native onPress() is either always called or never called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When my onPress is like this:

```
<Button
  onPress={() => this.switchview(newview)}
  title="whatever">
</Button>
```

it isn't called, even when I press the button. But when it is like this:

```
<Button
  onPress={this.switchview(newview)}
  title="whatever">
</Button>
```

it is always called, even when I don't press the button. My goal is to run this when I press the button. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The second one is obviously wrong. You are calling the function `switchView()` the value whatever your `switchView()` return will be assigned to `onPress`. Give more details like errors etc, to help

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the onPress inside the brackets.

```
<Button onPress{() => {this.switchview(newview)}}></Button>
```

Whatever is between the button tags will typically appear as the text of the button, whatever attributes you want to add to the button you need to put inside the brackets where you declare the button.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, you are using the props of button after closing the angle bracket as `<Button>`.You should probably do like this below:

```
<Button
  onPress={() => this.switchview(newview)}
  title="whatever">
</Button>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In

constrctor(){

this.switchview=this.switchview.bind(this);

}

Click Me

Than use it.
Try and let me know.

Comment: I tried doing this, but it didn't help. My function declaration is also in the constructor, if that is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `.bind(...)` for this:

```
<Button
    onPress={this.switchview.bind(this, newview)}
    title="whatever">
</Button>
```

This will pass a new function to the button, which will have `this` equal the `this` in the current context, and have the first argument be `newview`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this.

```
 <Button onPress={() => this.switchview(newview)} 
         title="Learn More"/>
```